# discord.py Как я могу уличить пользователя в спаме?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

discord.py Разрабатываю собственного бота для собственного сервера. Возник вопрос: Как я могу уличить пользователя в спаме текстовыми сообщениями с помощью бота?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо создать два файла - `any_name.txt` и `spam_detect.txt`. Далее просто используйте этот код.

```
import asyncio

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")
    while True:
        print("cleared")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        with open("any_name.txt", "r+") as file:
        file.truncate(0)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
counter = 0
with open("spam_detect.txt", "r+") as file:
    for lines in file:
        if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.auth.id):
        counter+=1
        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        if counter > 5:
            await message.guild.ban(message.author, readon="spammer")
            await syncio.sleep(1)
            await message.guild.unban(message.author)
            print("Oops")
```

Автор - https://raviblog.medium.com/how-to-make-a-discord-antispam-bot-using-python-6f0f90a7c307